# How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium Webdriver (Python) using a variable name to store the string?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following line to select an element that finds specific text on a webpage:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'my string')]")
```

And this works fine.

But, if I assign the string to a variable and try to use the variable in the line (as below), I get an exception stating that the expression is not legal.

```
varname = 'my string'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), varname)]")
```

I would like to repeat this search multiple times for a handful of strings without having to write the line over and over again. My end goal is to have a list of strings which I iterate over, something like this:

```
mystrings = ('my first string','my second string','my third string')
for x in mystrings:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), x)]")
```

Answer (score 2):

because it is literally looking for the text "varname". you need to format the text to pass the variable:

```
varname = 'my string'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % varname)  # option 1
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{0}')]".format(varname))  # option 2
```

either option will work, just depends on how you like to format your strings.

similarly for the list:

```
mystrings = ['my first string','my second string','my third string']
for x in mystrings:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % x)
```

EDIT: forgot to include the single quotes. code updated.